# How to manage non-autoincrement primary key in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, primary-key

I have lots of situations where I'd like to have a non-autoincrement primary key when using Rails.

Example: I have one-to-one relationship between A and B. B describes some specific features added to A thus can't exist without A. So we have:

A has one B
B belongs to A

The natural thinking would be having B.A_id as primary key. So I tried `create_table b, :id=>false` in migration and `set_primary_key :a_id` in B's model, but it doesn't create actual primary keys in the database. And I want them (as well as foreign keys), as the database will be used not only by this Rails app.

If I create primary keys with execute they don't land in 
 schema.rb, which hurts. Now I'm thinking about a workaround: I can live without PK constraint as long as there's unique constraint for that column, so I can use Rails' add_index in the migration which seems more elegant.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use an sql based schema? Sure its not database agnostic but database agnosticism is overrated, especially when it prevents you from getting things done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[A very similar question on StackOverflow suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585323/how-to-turn-off-autoincrement-in-rails-active-record) trying something like:

```
create_table(:b, :id => false) do |t|
  t.integer :a_id, :options => 'PRIMARY KEY'
end
```