# No autoincrement primary key ID in Rails Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Flag -> This is a noob question!

In Rails Migration File is possible to create a column ID primary_key no auto_increment?

Comment: It has been asked before  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894504/how-to-manage-non-autoincrement-primary-key-in-rails

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off auto_increment in Rails Active Record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585323/how-to-turn-off-auto-increment-in-rails-active-record)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded dropping auto_increment by running following change_column method.

```
class DropAutoIncrement < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :my_table, :id, :integer
  end
end
```

I used activerecord 4.0.2.

Comment: Hi @Yuki, I'm trying to achieve the same thing on my PostgreSQL database. Did you encounter any problem or side effects after doing that? Thanks

Comment: I don't drop auto_inrement on primary key in the production so I'm not sure the detail. Major side effect is we need to manage primary key instead of managing by ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that Yuki´s answer got too old?
It didn´t work for me.
But the following worked:

```
class CreateNoAutoincrement < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def up
    create_table( :my_table, :id => false ) {|t|
      t.integer :id,    null: false ;
      t.string  :token, null: false ;
    }
    add_index :my_table, :id,    unique: true ;
    add_index :my_table, :token, unique: true ;
  end
  def down
    drop_table :my_table ;
  end
end
```

On MariaDB the table looks like this:

```
MariaDB [foo_devel]> describe my_table ;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| token | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

It´s nice, that I still get a primary key, not just two Unique Indexes
(probably because the column name is 'id')