# How to insert primary key value explicitly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table called *messages* and here is the table structure,  I don’t want *id* is auto increment field but it should be a primary key for that table.

Here is table structure for *messages*

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
      `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      `text` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `source` VARCHAR(100),
      `created_at` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );
```

while insert the data into table I am using below hash object

```
msg['id'] = 12345; 
msg['user_id'] = 1;
msg['text'] = 'Hello world';
```

If I save this hash into messages table, id is not inserting

```
message = Message.new(msg);
message.save!
```

Rails is building insert sql with out *id*, so *id* value is not inserting messages table.

How insert the id value in table, This the insert sql rails build with out using *id* field

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`updated_at`, `user_id `, `text`, `created_at`) VALUES('2010-06-18 12:01:05', '1', 'Hello world', '2010-06-18 12:01:05');
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting ID value is often useful when migrating from legacy data or - as I am doing right now - merging two apps while preserving FK integrity.

I just scratched my head for a while and it seems you have to set the PK value **before** calling *save*. After the record is saved, ActiveRecord ignores #id= or update_attribute . So while setting up the record from an attribute hash I use:

```
article = Article.new(attrs)
article.id = attrs["id"]
article.save!
```

Answer (score 0):

You're working against the way rails works. ActiveRecord reserves the use of the *id* column and manages it for you.

- Why should *id* not be an auto-incrementing column if it's the primary key?
- Why do you need to control its value?

If you need an id column you can control yourself, add another one. It won't be the primary key, but you can make it a unique index too.

Comment: This is a testament against Rails if I ever heard one.

Comment: @cookiecaper your comment sounds like a prejudice, or troll. Not productive. [Surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) is a long-accepted database practice that Rails is built around. I should add that there are [ways to work around it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585323/how-to-turn-off-auto-increment-in-rails-active-record). It's not impossible, but you might just be shooting yourself in the foot for no good reason.

Comment: You can set it if you do ```message.id = some_value```, before calling ```message.save```

Comment: I didn't down vote but I don't think this is a complete answer. I agree this is not the "Rails way" but Legacy databases just don't care about Rails.