# Passing primary key to create action via CSV upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, csv

I'm trying to bulk upload via CSV. Here's my import method from my controller:

```
def import
        params.permit(:id, :brand, :product, :details)
        Item.import(params[:file])
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Products imported."
    end
```

Which then calls this self.import method from my Item model.

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
       Item.create! row.to_hash
    end
end
```

Here's my form for upload:

```
<%= form_tag import_item_mgmt_index_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

Here's my issue: when I check the data in the db, rails is assigning an auto-incrementing `item_id` instead of the `item_id` passed from my CSV file. I need to assign these specific id's for my app, and I'm not sure why I can't assign them upon creation. Looking at the params, I don't even see my `item_id` getting passed. Help? Thanks in advance.

**Item Model**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many    :inventory_items
has_many    :vendors, through: :inventory_items
has_many  :list_items
has_many  :shopping_lists, through: :list_items

searchable do
text :brand, :stored => true
text :details, :stored => true
text :product, :stored => true
integer :id, :references, :stored => true
end
end
```

Comment: What does your `Item` model look like?

Comment: Updated with Item model.

Comment: What model is `item_id` stored in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is might work.

First you'll have to adjust your table structure according to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585323/how-to-turn-off-auto-increment-in-rails-active-record) to turn of the auto-increment

```
create_table(:table_name, :id => false) do |t|
  t.integer :id, :options => 'PRIMARY KEY'
end
```

If this doesn't work on it's own, add the following line to your model.

```
set_primary_key :id
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in my app. From the additional research I did, it sounds like trying to work against rails like this may cause problems if the app becomes more complex. I went ahead and added a `product_code` bigint field in my item table, and ran my association off of that. Seems to be working okay for now.