# Rails 4 migration: Create mysql table with primary key but without auto_increment

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

possible duplicate [How to turn off auto_increment in Rails Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585323/how-to-turn-off-auto-increment-in-rails-active-record)

New to rails, I want to create a `fm_zipcodes` table `zipcode` as primary key but I don't want extra `auto_increment`. I have tried different ways but none of them working for me and `auto_increment` not reflecting in `db/schema.rb` file.

```
create_table :fm_zipcodes, :primary_key => :zipcode do |t|
  t.integer :state_id, null: false
  ..
end
```

close answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17960388/1093542

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off auto\_increment in Rails Active Record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585323/how-to-turn-off-auto-increment-in-rails-active-record)

Comment: Do you want to have both tables `zipcodes` and `fm_zipcodes`? Or just one `fm_zipcodes` table with a `zipcode` column?

Comment: @spickermann, its fm_zipcodes, updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
# in your migration
def up
  create_table :fm_zipcodes, id: false do |t|
    t.integer :zipcode, null: false
    # ...
  end
  add_index :fm_zipcodes, :zipcode, unique: true
end

# in your FmZipcode model
self.primary_key = 'zipcode'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create_table :fm_zipcodes do |t|
  t.integer :zipcode, null: false
# ...
end
add_foreign_key :fm_zipcodes, :zipcode
```

more infomation please see http://api.rubyonrails.org/?q=add_foreign_key

Comment: The OP doesn't want to have a foreign key to a `zipcodes` table. He wants to have a `zipcode` column on the `fm_zipcodes` table that acts as the primary key.